# PHP upload CSV is not echoing any data

Tags: php, csv

I have this PHP code:

```
//start to process file
//first, move file on to server
echo("Uploading raw file...");
$file1_name=$_FILES['dd_submission_form']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file ( "$file1_name","dd_submission_form.csv") or die("file did not copy<br>");
echo("Done<br/>");

//now open file using sequential access
echo("Opening file...");
$file_handle = fopen("dd_submission_form.csv", "r");

//read in just the first row at the moment to get call plan metadata (column headings)
$first_line=fgetcsv($file_handle);

while (($data = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
{
    echo $data[0];
}

fclose($file_handle);

print "Import done";
```

and when i upload a CSV file, its just showing

> Uploading raw file...Done
>   Opening file...Import done

even though i have echoed `$data[0];` this should display the data from the column A in the CSV file but nothing

the .csv file copies to the server fine

Comment: please share few lines of your CSV, may be the format is not understood

Comment: what is result of `var_dump( file_exists( $file1_name ) );`

Comment: All your text outputting means is that PHP is interpreting up to that point in the code.  It tells you nothing whether you were given errors or bad return values.  When you code, make sure you code for any return value you expect, including `NULL`, `FALSE`, errors, or exceptions.  Use http://www.php.net as a reference for all your function calls and to verify you will accept the proper return values in **any** scenario.  You can then begin to debug your code by seeing/dumping those return values to verify they are what you expect (or that they aren't).

Answer (score 0):

I replicate your code:

```
<form action="#" name='form1' enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="dd_submission_form">
    <input type="submit" name='invia'>
</form>

<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_POST);

if (isset($_FILES['dd_submission_form'])){

//start to process file
//first, move file on to server
    echo("Uploading raw file...");
    $file1_name = $_FILES['dd_submission_form']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file("$file1_name", "dd_submission_form.csv") or die("file did not copy<br>");

    echo("Done<br/>");

//now open file using sequential access
    echo("Opening file...");
    $file_handle = fopen("dd_submission_form.csv", "r");

//read in just the first row at the moment to get call plan metadata (column headings)
    $first_line = fgetcsv($file_handle);

    while (($data = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
        echo $data[0];
    }

    fclose($file_handle);

    print "Import done";

} else {
    echo "<div>load file</div>";
}
```

I test it with following CSV

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
1,2,3,4
a,b,c,d
I,II,III,IV
alpha,beta,gamma,delta
```

and everything works as you expected, so I think that the problem is the format of CSV.

**Can you post a portion of your CSV?**